# Regex with awk gensub() is not matching

Tags: regex, bash, awk

```
#!/bin/bash

t="_tmp"

for f in $(find . -name '*.java') 
do

  tf=$f$t #temp file name
  awk '{gensub("/([_a-zA-Z]*)\.methodName\(\)/", "_newClass.methodCall\(\\1\.newMethodName\(\),\\1\)", "g");}' $f > $tf && mv $tf $f

done
```

Basically I am looking for instances of

xxx.methodName()

and trying to replace it with

_newClass.methodCall(xxx.newMethodName(),xxx)

Where xxx is any variable name that occurs before the methodName call. right now I have a file that contains

```
"stuff"
m.methodName()
"stuff"{m.methodName()
"stuff"
```

and nothing is happening. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following awk script:

```
{
    print gensub(/([_a-zA-Z]*)\.methodName\(\)/,            \
    "_newClass.methodCall(\\1.newMethodName(),\\1)", "g")        
}
```

You forgot to print the result of `gensub`. It does not modify $0 by default.

Comment: Thank you! I notice my escape sequences and quotation marks were also a off. I appreciate the help.

Comment: You should use `[_[:alpha:]]` instead of `[_a-zA-Z]` to avoid locale issues (don't ask me what - they exist but I always just use the right character classes so I don't need to think about them). Also, though he didn't show it, I suspect the OP probably really wants `[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*` since he seems to be looking for a class name and those can't be empty, must start with a letter or underscore, and can include digits. `[[:alnum:]_]` can be abbreviated to `\w` if you care since you're using gawk anyway.